# Direct assignment of a model to variable in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, oop, codeigniter-3

I know in CodeIgniter, in a controller, you can instantiate a class like this:

```
$this->load->model('Data_model');
$data = new \Data_model;
```

But is there any more direct way to get to `$data` like this?

```
$data = $this->load->model('Data_model', true);
```

I saw something like that loading a database connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code for call model and use

```
$this->load->model('Model_Name');
$model = $this->Model_Name;
$some_var = $model->func();
```

or

```
$this->load->model('Model_Name','modelname');
$model = $this->modelname;
$some_var = $model->func();
```

if you called models in `application/config/autoload.php`

```
$autoload['model'] = array('Model_Name');
```

you can use this way

```
$model = $this->Model_Name
```